# Support of Element "pre" in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

According to the [migration guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/migrate.html#configuration-options-compatibility-table), the `<pre>` element ("format_pre") is no longer available in CKEditor 5.

However, I was still able to configure it as a formatting option for CKEditor 5 using the options for the heading:

`{ model: 'formatted', view: 'pre', title: 'Formatted' }`

Is this correct or should `<pre>` elements (markup created with CKEditor 4) be replaced by [code blocks](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/code-blocks.html) (`<pre><code>...</code></pre>`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this works because it is possible to define custom elements for the [heading](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/headings.html#configuring-custom-heading-elements)